# cannot install mysql server

Tags: apt, server, mysql, dependencies, 20.10

Shows this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-cluster-community-client : Depends: libncurses5 (>= 6) but it is not installable
                                  
Depends: libtinfo5 (>= 6) but it is not installable
                                  
Depends: mysql-cluster-community-client-core (= 8.0.24-1ubuntu18.04) but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-cluster-community-server-core : Depends: libaio1 (>= 0.3.93) but it is not installable
                                       
Depends: libmecab2 but it is not installable
                                       
Recommends: mecab-ipadic-utf8 but it is not installable

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Do you want MySQL Server, or MySQL Cluster Server?

Comment: What command are you running ? Did you run `sudo apt update` first ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem though not identical. Purging and reinstalling mysql worked for me. Steps: https://linuxscriptshub.com/uninstall-completely-remove-mysql-ubuntu-16-04/